# Adding pictures to Bokeh stackedbarchart

Tags: python, bokeh

I have created a stacked barchart in Bokeh and now would like to add pictures to the hoverTool as I have seen it has been done here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html

```
output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    imgs=[
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
    ],
    fonts=[
        '<i>italics</i>',
        '<pre>pre</pre>',
        '<b>bold</b>',
        '<small>small</small>',
        '<del>del</del>'
    ]
))

TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <img
                src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                border="2"
            ></img>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
            <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```

However I am struggeling to make it work for my code. For an example I have added a part of my dataframe:

```
temp=pd.DataFrame( {'bydelsnavn': {0: 'Amager Vest', 1: 'Amager Øst', 2: 'Bispebjerg', 3: 'Brønshøj-Husum', 4: 'Indre By', 5: 'Nørrebro', 6: 'Valby', 7: 'Vanløse', 8: 'Vesterbro', 9: 'Østerbro'}, 'Alder': {0: 53.0, 1: 21.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 9.0, 4: 4.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 3.0, 7: 44.0, 8: 46.0, 9: 59.0}, 'Alderm': {0: 63.0, 1: 32.0, 2: 49.0, 3: 13.0, 4: 45.0, 5: 55.0, 6: 104.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 50.0, 9: 4.0}, 'Apple': {0: 94.0, 1: 109.0, 2: 115.0, 3: 12.0, 4: 22.0, 5: 81.0, 6: 41.0, 7: 3.0, 8: 132.0, 9: 51.0}, 'Alder_p': {0: 21.9, 1: 8.68, 2: 0.41, 3: 3.72, 4: 1.65, 5: 0.83, 6: 1.24, 7: 18.18, 8: 19.01, 9: 24.38}, 'Alderm_p': {0: 15.18, 1: 7.71, 2: 11.81, 3: 3.13, 4: 10.84, 5: 13.25, 6: 25.06, 7: 0.0, 8: 12.05, 9: 0.96}, 'Apple_p': {0: 14.24, 1: 16.52, 2: 17.42, 3: 1.82, 4: 3.33, 5: 12.27, 6: 6.21, 7: 0.45, 8: 20.0, 9: 7.73}})
```

And my current code looks like this:

```
# Create an empty figure
p = figure(x_range = temp['bydelsnavn'].values,plot_width = 700, plot_height=400, 
           title='Tree pr. district', toolbar_sticky = False,
           tools = 'pan,wheel_zoom,reset')

colornames = ['#c6a5c1','#77c6ba','#90318e']

treeName = temp.columns[1:4]

# Stacked bar chart
renderers = p.vbar_stack(stackers=treeName,x='bydelsnavn',source=temp,
            width=0.8, color = colornames)

# Add the hover tool
for r in renderers:
    tree = r.name
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ("%s" % tree, "@{%s}" % tree)
    ], renderers = [r])
    p.add_tools(hover)

# remove the grid
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color=None
# Make sure bars stat at 0
p.y_range.start = 0
# remove - y-axis
p.yaxis.visible = False
# Remove the grey box around the plot
p.outline_line_color = None
# Turn the x-labels
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.5
# Remove tool bar logo
p.toolbar.logo = None
# Move the border of the left side to show "Amager"
p.min_border_left = 30

show(p)
```

How do I add an image to the HoverTool? For example if I wanted to add this picture to all 3 tree types: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Apfelbaum_Winterrambour_Hochstamm.jpg

## Edit below:

After reading a comment I have changed my code so I now have a source and I have changed the tooltip to fit my needs.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    bydelsnavn=['Amager Vest', 'Amager Øst', 'Bispebjerg', 'Brønshøj-Husum',
               'Indre By', 'Nørrebro', 'Valby', 'Vanløse', 'Vesterbro','Østerbro'],
    Alder = [53., 21.,  1.,  9.,  4.,  2.,  3., 44., 46., 59.],
    Alderm = [ 63.,  32.,  49.,  13.,  45.,  55., 104.,   0.,  50.,   4.],
    Apple = [ 94., 109., 115.,  12.,  22.,  81.,  41.,   3., 132.,  51.],
    imgs = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/CopalmeDAmerique.jpg/800px-CopalmeDAmerique.jpg',
            'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg',
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Apfelbaum_Winterrambour_Hochstamm.jpg']    
    ))
```

```
TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <img
                src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                border="2"
            ></img>
        </div>
    </div>
"""
```

And I have added `tooltips=TOOLTIPS`in the `figure`and changed the `source=source` in the `renderers`.

In the source I have added three pictures for the three tree types, however at the moment I am actually adding an image to each `bydelsnavn` and not to the three type, how can I control this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each renderer has to have its own image, you cannot incorporate the image data within the data source. But since you're already using a separate hover tool for each renderer, you can just directly embed image URL within the tooltip HTML template.

The code below demonstrates it by using the HTML that Bokeh generates for tooltips when you pass a list of tuples to `HoverTool`. But it can be adapted to your needs.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    bydelsnavn=['Amager Vest', 'Amager Øst', 'Bispebjerg', 'Brønshøj-Husum',
                'Indre By', 'Nørrebro', 'Valby', 'Vanløse', 'Vesterbro', 'Østerbro'],
    Alder=[53., 21., 1., 9., 4., 2., 3., 44., 46., 59.],
    Alderm=[63., 32., 49., 13., 45., 55., 104., 0., 50., 4.],
    Apple=[94., 109., 115., 12., 22., 81., 41., 3., 132., 51.]))

p = figure(x_range=sorted(set(source.data['bydelsnavn'])), plot_width=700, plot_height=400,
           title='Tree pr. district', toolbar_sticky=False,
           tools='pan,wheel_zoom,reset')

colornames = ['#c6a5c1', '#77c6ba', '#90318e']

treeName = ['Alder', 'Alderm', 'Apple']
images = {'Alder': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/CopalmeDAmerique.jpg/800px-CopalmeDAmerique.jpg',
          'Alderm': 'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg',
          'Apple': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Apfelbaum_Winterrambour_Hochstamm.jpg'}

renderers = p.vbar_stack(stackers=treeName, x='bydelsnavn', source=source,
                         width=0.8, color=colornames)

for r in renderers:
    tree = r.name
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=f"""\
    <div style="display: table; border-spacing: 2px;">
      <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;" class="bk-tooltip-row-label">
          {tree}
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" class="bk-tooltip-row-value">
          @{{{tree}}}
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" class="bk-tooltip-row-value">
          <img style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;" src="{images[tree]}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    """, renderers=[r])
    p.add_tools(hover)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
p.yaxis.visible = False
p.outline_line_color = None
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.5
p.toolbar.logo = None
# Move the border of the left side to show "Amager"
p.min_border_left = 30

show(p)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried to implement it to the best of my ability but I do not understand how I can pass an image to each tree type instead of passing it to each city district? I have edited the post above so it also includes my new `source`.

Comment: To be sure - you want to have one picture for Alder, one for Alderm, and one for Apple?

Comment: Yes, excatly :-)

Comment: Dude you are awesome, thank you so much! This plot is gonna be so sick now!